# GGally only density plot no scatter in the figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

This is the figure Im getting [image] what I would like to get is only the density instead of the scatter, how do i get that this ?

The function that is used here is part of the MOFA2 [package](https://rdrr.io/github/bioFAM/MOFA2/src/R/plot_factors.R) I tried tinkering around the source code by charging the dot_size parameter to `0` but no effect.

The actual code which I used to plot this

```
plot_factors(MOFAobject, 
  factors = 1:3,
  color_by = "RISK_CYTO"
)
```

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

**Data update**
[MOFA](https://raw.githack.com/bioFAM/MOFA2_tutorials/master/R_tutorials/getting_started_R.html)

```
dt = fread("ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/mofa/getting_started/data.txt.gz")
head(dt)
dt[,group:=NULL]
MOFAobject <- create_mofa(dt)
print(MOFAobject)
data_opts <- get_default_data_options(MOFAobject)
head(data_opts)
model_opts <- get_default_model_options(MOFAobject)
head(model_opts)
train_opts <- get_default_training_options(MOFAobject)
head(train_opts)
MOFAobject <- prepare_mofa(
  object = MOFAobject,
  data_options = data_opts,
  model_options = model_opts,
  training_options = train_opts
)
```

Train the MOFA model

```
outfile = file.path(getwd(),"model.hdf5")
MOFAobject.trained <- run_mofa(MOFAobject, outfile)
```

Plot factors

```
 plot_factors(MOFAobject, 
      factors = 1:3,
      color_by = "group"
    )
```

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Comment: @deschen actually the MOFA object is huge and I can't `dput(head)` either since its not 'dataframe' let me see the default example given in manual

Comment: @deschen updated the question with simulated data from the MOFA library